# How to avoid line break in Typography

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a material ui `Typography` which is giving line break even though space is there, Below is the code

```
  <Box flexDirection="row">
  <Typography>
    Gender:
    <RadioGroup
      row
      aria-label="gender"
      name="gender1"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
      <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
      <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
    </RadioGroup>
  </Typography>
</Box>
```

How to display 'Gender' and 'Radio' buttons both in one row. Here is my codesandbox [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-tr7f3?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#grid) within Box

```
<Box flexDirection="row" >
      <Grid container direction="row"
      justify="space-evenly"
       alignItems="center">
         <Grid item>
           <Typography>
             Gender:
           </Typography>
         </Grid>
         <Grid item>
           <RadioGroup
              row
              aria-label="gender"
              name="gender1"
              value={value}
              onChange={handleChange}> 
             <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
             <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
             <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
           </RadioGroup>
         </Grid>
        </Grid>          
    </Box>
```

codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-45rb5)

Comment: Thanks, just one query, how to get rid of this extra space between 'Gender' and 'Radio' buttons

Comment: You can replace **justify="space-evenly"** with **spacing={2}**